Issues with Dataprovider with validation functions for each row in xls
I have the following class
pulbic class DataProiders {

@DataProvider(name="data")
public String[][] getAllData() throws IOException {
// Using XLUtils class which uses XSSWorkbook to get cell data
//Take the  name of the xls file and sheet name and calculate row and column count
//two for loops rowcount and columncount to get all data and return the data
}

//I have the test clsss test.java
public class CutomerRecords {

pulbic Response response;
public static JSONObject resJsonObj;

@Test(priority = 1, dataProvider = "data", dataProviderClass = DataProviders.class)
public void CustomerData(String cId, String fName, String lName, String email, String postCode){
//These are the 5 columns in the xls sheet
//set method to set all the parameters using pojo class for request

//Call the POST API and get the response back
response = PostMehtodFromAPIClass(request)
resJsonOj= new JSONObject(response.getBody().asString());
}

@Test(priority=2)
public void validateResponseCusID(){
//my validation logic using resJsonObj
}

@Test(priority=2)
public void validateResponseCusName(){
//my validation logic using resJsonObj
}

@Test(priority=2)
public void validateResponseCusPostCode(){
//my validation logic using resJsonObj
}

@Test(priority=2)
public void validateResponseCusEmail(){
//my validation logic using resJsonObj
}

Here, my requirement is first execute CustomerData for first row in xls sheet and continue the each validation responbse test functions, then read the second row and test validate resonse.
But what is happening is if I have 5 rows in xls, it executes 5 rows and only for last row the validation response functions are working. I need a suggestion to read one row at atime and call the validation functions, then second row and validations, and so on.

The problem is in your test code. You are having a static data member which is going to remember the last assignment. That explains why the other two tests are basically only executing for the last iteration.
What you need is a TestNG factory.
Here's a sample that shows how to work with factories.
public record Student(int id, String name, String address) { }

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

public class DataProviders {

    @DataProvider(name = "data")
    public Object[][] getAllData() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {new Student(20, "Alpha", "Chennai")},
                {new Student(22, "Beta", "Bangalore")},
                {new Student(23, "Gamma", "Hyderabad")},
        };
    }
}

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import org.testng.annotations.Factory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class CustomerRecordsTest {

    private final Student student;
    private JsonObject resJsonObj;
    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Factory(dataProvider = "data", dataProviderClass = DataProviders.class)
    public CustomerRecordsTest(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void customerData() {
        resJsonObj = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(student), JsonObject.class);
    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void validateResponseCusID(){
        System.err.println("Student id = " + resJsonObj.get("id"));
    }

    @Test(priority=3)
    public void validateResponseCusName(){
        System.err.println("Student name = " + resJsonObj.get("name"));
    }

    @Test(priority=4)
    public void validateResponseCusPostCode(){
        System.err.println("Student address = " + resJsonObj.get("address"));
    }
}

For more details on TestNG factories refer to : https://testng.org/#_factories

Thanks. I am not able to use the Factory annotation. Getting the compile error saying the function must return Object[]. I am not sure why and what to return here.

Yes. The @Factory annotation can be used either on top of a constructor (this tells TestNG that to produce new objects it just needs to invoke the parameterised constructor) (or) you can create a static method that returns Object[] array (this tells TestNG that it should invoke the static method to get the test class instances). The example I shared uses a factory powered by the constructor and to ensure i get multiple instances, i am tying the factory to a data provider.

So the data provider will return different sets of values, which will be consumed by the constructor to produce multiple test class instances. the number of instances produced will be directly equal to the number of iterations that the data provider has (or) it would be equal to the number of objects in your Object[] array (if you used a static method to produce instances)

Thanks for the explanation. It was very good technical summary to correct my code and it is working fine for me.
